# custom close button for youtube popup

Tags: html, css, youtube, popup

I have a youtube video pop up that works well but I want to include a custom close button. I have done research but this has all come to nothing so I am hoping my stack buddies can help.

Comment: I don't think we can help if we have no code to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What I am estmiating from your question is you want a custom close button to close the DIV or iframe that your YouTube videos are in.  I suggest jQuery for this:

```
$(function(){

  $(".closeBtn").click(function(){
    $($(this).data("target")).hide();
  });

});
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<div class="video" id="v1">
    <div class="closeBtn" data-target="#v1"></div>

  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XeroElixir/z8GQJ/)

What the data-target (`data-target="#v1"`) does is target the ID of the div (`<div class="video" id="v1">`) then in jQuery, adding the animation effect `.hide()` , `.fadeOut(500)` to the ID.